# How to find earliest upcoming date given a list of weekdays?

Tags: php, date

Dates in PHP are a nightmare for me so please help me out fellow coders... I want to notify customers about the day their order will be delivered. It works like this:

I have 2 shipping zones, A & B. Orders for zone A are delivered each Monday, Wednesday & Friday, whereas zone B is on Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday. For each order, the delivery day is scheduled for the NEXT AVAILABLE day, depending on the zone. Please consider that if someone places an order on Monday the goods will be delivered on the NEXT available date, that would be Tuesday for zone B and Wednesday for zone A.

How can I calculate the NEXT AVAILABLE delivery date and notify the customer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Info
$date = array(date("d"), date("m"), date("Y"));
$zone = "A";
// ------

$zones = array("A" => array(1 => "Monday",    
                            3 => "Wednesday", 
                            5 => "Friday")     

              ,"B" => array(2 => "Tuesday",    
                            4 => "Thursday",   
                            6 => "Saturday")); 

$found = false;
$days_plus = 1; // always next day

// Retrieve last day from the zone
end($zones[$zone]);
$last_day = key($zones[$zone]);

do {
    $mk = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[1], ($date[0] + $days_plus), $date[2]);
    $week = date("w", $mk);

    // if week not passed last day of zone
    if ($week <= $last_day)
    {
        if (!isset($zones[$zone][$week]))
        {
            $days_plus++;
        }
        else
        {
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $days_plus++;
    }
} while (!$found);

echo "Next date: " . date("d/m/Y - l", $mk);
```

Comment: Tested and it works like a charm. Great skills, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This will certainly not be the fastest or most clever answer, but it's going to be a pleasure to read the code.

Assuming we are shipping in zone A:

```
$dates = array(
    new DateTime('next monday'), // magic!
    new DateTime('next wednesday'),
    new DateTime('next friday'),
);

// Seems to work because since PHP 5.2.2 DateTime objects
// can be compared with the < and > operators    
$shippingDate = min($dates);

echo $shippingDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

You might want to take a look at the [relative date formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) available in PHP, this is the part where the "next monday" magic happens. For information on what you can do with `$shippingDate`, see the documentation on class [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

### Update

For completeness, here is a more old-school version which does not need PHP 5.3 and should also be faster (although speed is practically irrelevant here). I don't like it as much, because it's not easy to verify that it works correctly. In contrast to the version above, this one had a bug when I first wrote it. Simple is good.

```
$today = date('w');

// These values are from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
$shippingDays = array(
    1, // mon
    3, // wed
    5, // fri
);

// Each of these weekdays is how many days into the future?
foreach($shippingDays as &$day) {
    $day = (7 + $day - $today) % 7;
}

// Get the earliest one, but not if it's today
// array_filter is used to remove a possible 0
$daysInFuture = min(array_filter($shippingDays));
$shippingDate = new DateTime('+'.$daysInFuture.' days');
echo $shippingDate->format('Y-m-d');
```

**[See it in action](http://www.ideone.com/LNFBb)**.

Comment: `$shippingDate = min($dates);`

Comment: @salathe: I tested this and it works in practice, thanks for the heads up. But can you point me to where it's documented? I would be unwilling to use something I can't find in the docs, even if it makes life easier.

Comment: It is not documented, nor should it be, that `min()` (or `max()`) would work with an array of DateTime objects. However, they can be compared (e.g. using `>`, `<` and friends) as mentioned [here](http://php.net/datetime.diff) and from there, having `min()` work makes sense.

Comment: P.S. take it from me that you can and should (no reason why not to) use `min()` in place of the `usort()/reset()` combo.

Comment: @salathe: Well, I very much disagree with the "nor should it be" part. Also, "take it from me" does not sound convincing to me since I 'd like to call myself a professional. **However**, since the comparison operators are documented to work, and `min` has been demonstrated to work, and it's reasonable to assume that `min` utilizes the same feature as the comparison operators, in the end we do agree that `min` is the preferable choice here.

Comment: where do we draw the line: list *every* function that works/doesn't work with a particular object, or with an array containing instances of a single class? Would the "take it from me" sound more convincing if it came from a PHP core developer, or PHP manual author? Maybe I'm not professional enough to be handing out suggestions for you.

Comment: @salathe: I apologize if my previous comment offended you, it was certainly not meant to. But please consider that we now know (after looking up the docs!) that on PHP 5.2.0 *you could not compare `DateTime` objects with `operator <`*! PHP is a mess in this department, unlike say C# or C++ where everything is adequately documented. So *in this particular case*, I would draw the line at "someone who has seen relevant source or documentation tells me about it".

Comment: the documentation is an ongoing process and there are many problems with keeping the docs up to date, especially relatively small changes/additions like this—that's where bug reports are so valuable. Just to be clear, the `<` and `>` style comparisons of DateTime objects are available as of **PHP 5.2.2** (so that's when `min()` also works for them). Clarifying this in the docs is on my todo list ([bug](http://bugs.php.net/55652)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('next Monday');
$date      = date('Y-m-d', $timestamp);
```